# Dialogue Chain Differences: TV versus Film

Tags: mix, compression, eq

How is your processing chain different? Certainly, limiting and dialnorm requirements are different...but what about your actual processing?  Do you step compress on some genres and quick attack bus compress on others? Does it matter if it is a "walk and talk" verse a "Action" film?

Answer (score 4):

GENERALLY (because as you well know, every project is different), the difference is that I tend to use more compression on TV, because a) I have to hit a LKFS spec and b) I usually have far less time to ride levels so multiple compressors can go a long way. In film I usually start with very minimal processing on the bus... just a peak limiter and then add only what I absolutely need to. With TV shows I usually have a template/program that may include, NR, EQ and compression. These are usually setup on the first ep, and then tweaked as needed.